# Troubleshooting disk space allowance overuse

Tags: apache-2.2, storage

I regularly accrue charges for disk space allowance overuse.  I'm in a shared hosting environment.  I've gone through and deactivated logs and removed files, but seems like every month, I'm right back where I was...

Are there certain things I should look for, or that contribute to overuse?

Comment: What OS? Do you have root access? Shell access? Are you allowing file uploads? What else could be causing disk space to accumulate?

Answer (score 2):

What are your current disk space allotments?  Generally speaking, it might be better to find a different host (one that fits into your specific requirements) then to be nickled and dimed to death for overages.

Answer (score 2):

1. Perform a disk space audit.

   - If your audit does not reveal a problem ask your provider for *their* data.
   - If your audit does reveal that you're over your alloted disk quota:

     1. Determine what is using the space.
     2. Determine if you need it.

        - If you need it, either pay the overages, change hosting plans or seek a new provider.
        - If you don't need it, delete it.

If you have shell access to the server you can use `du` to report on your disk usage (assuming it's a unix box since you tagged the question with [apache2](/questions/tagged/apache2)).